# contact form 7 wordpress plugin not working properly

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using contact form 7 wordpress plugin for one of website and facing problem to adding action after sending mail.

I want to call some CRM Api when data submitted by the user and also sent mail to admin so i have tried following way.

I added action and function to function.php

1) 
    add_action('init', create_function('',
    'add_action("wpcf7_admin_after_mail", "leads_integration_wp_cf7");'));

```
function leads_integration_wp_cf7($cf7 ) {

$title = $contact_form->title;
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if($submission)
{
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    //using curl make request here
}
```

}

So using this way i got mail but i am thinking my function(leads_integration_wp_cf7) did not called and i did not get entry in CRM.

2)

```
add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'leads_integration_wp_cf7');
```

using this way i made successfully request to CRM but mail sending stop.on a form page ajax preloader loading,loading, and not redirect on url.

Anybody face this issue i am new in wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action `wpcf7_admin_after_mail` is called in `edit-contact-form.php` file and it is used for form control ui purpose so it will not be helpful for this case.

The action `wpcf7_before_send_mail` is correct for doing some task when contact form is posted and email is sent, can you confirm that mail is working properly if this action hook is not applied?

Also try renaming the param `$cf7` to `$contact_form`

```
function leads_integration_wp_cf7($cf7) {
```

To

```
function leads_integration_wp_cf7($contact_form) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay your are right we can put hook on this event wpcf7_before_send_mail,and now It working,there is problem in my api call code and some bug are generated that's why it stop.

Answer (score 0):

{code: 'invalid_json', message: 'The response is not a valid JSON response.'}
code: "invalid_json"
message: "The response is not a valid JSON response."

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To execute code after email has been sent, use `wpcf7_mail_sent` hook

```
// Add this code in functions.php
add_action('wpcf7_mail_sent', function ($cf7) {
    // Run code after the email has been sent
});
```

There is also `wpcf7_mail_failed`, which lets you hook into when the email fails.